# Why did my Mighty Mouse stop clicking?

Tags: macos, click, mouse

MMighty Mouse isn't so mighty since it won't click any more. Surprise is it does move the cursor around the screen. I have of course been through the Mouse and Bluetooth parameters to check for any potential "disable mouse clicking" button... in vain.

I've considered bringing it back to the Genius Bar but would like to solve it myself (and hopefully faster). Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Comment: is it possible there is some breakfast left over in it ?

Comment: Replacing the battery might help